# Can this PHP code be improved?

Tags: php

Is there a better way to do this simple task below?  Like with an array or even another method?

```
<?PHP
// current way
if ($city != NULL) {
    $city = FilterALLHTML($city);
}
if ($state != NULL) {
    $state = FilterALLHTML($state);
}
if ($title != NULL) {
    $title = FilterALLHTML($title);
}
if ($division != NULL) {
    $division = FilterALLHTML($division);
}
?>
```

Here is my current function

```
function FilterALLHTML($document) {
    //old array line //"'<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*//?//>'si",// strip html
    $text = strip_tags($document);
    $search = array ("/f.?u.?c.?k/i",
                 "/(s|$).?h.?i.?t/i",
                 '/(potspace|mycrib|palbolt)/i');
    $text = preg_replace ($search, '', $text);  
    return $text;
}
```

---

**UPDATE - Ok my new function after the suggestions from this post thanks guys**

```
function FilterALLHTML($var) {
    //old array line //"'<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*//?//>'si",// strip html
    if ($var != null){
        $text = strip_tags($var);
        $search = array ("/f.?u.?c.?k/i",
                     "/(s|$).?h.?i.?t/i",
                     '/(potspace|mycrib|palbolt|pot space)/i');
        $text = preg_replace ($search, '', $text);  
        return $text;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to prevent your users from saying "frutcake" or "as heist"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change your `FilterALLHTML` function to do the `null` check and have it return `null`?
Then you can throw away all the `if`s.

Example:

```
function FilterALLHTML($input)
{
    if ($input === null)
        return null;

    // Original code, I'll just use strip_tags() for a functional example
    return strip_tags($input);
}
```

**Edit:**

I felt like sharing an alternative to variable variables, as I don't really like the idea of using string literals instead of variable names. References all the way :)

```
function FilterALLHTML(&$text)
{
    if ($text !== null)
    {
        // Omitted regex bit for simplicity
        $text = strip_tags($text);
    }
}

$city = "<b>New York</b>";
$state = null;
$title = "<i>Mr.</i>";

$fields = array(&$city, &$state, &$title);
foreach ($fields as &$var)
    FilterALLHTML($var);
```

(*note: `FilterALLHTML` implementation differs from first example*)

Comment: +1 I like  your answer, maybe you could be a little more verbose in your reply for those who doesn't get it:)

Comment: Please comment on the downvote? I don't mind, but I would like some constructive criticism. Don't downvote just because it is not your answer :)

Comment: @Thorarin - from the looks of the thread, there was a drive-by downvoting.  I got hit too.  :/

Comment: @Thorarin & @Zombat, yes someone downvoted almost everyone to -1 and then I voted everyone up to 0 and 5 minutes later they were all -1 again, immature

Answer (score 9):

Yes, use PHP's [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
$vars = array('city','state','title','division');
foreach($vars as $v) {
    if ($$v != null) $$v = FilterAllHTML($$v);
}
```

If you know for a fact that all the variables have been previously defined, then you don't need the null check.  Otherwise, the null check will prevent E_NOTICE errors from triggering.

Comment: I will probably just add the check into my current function because I use that function very often I just put the 4 on this page for example but your code is really really cool!  I will deff. use that sometime thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach (array('city', 'state', 'title', 'division') as $var) {
    if ($$var != null) {
        $$var = FilterALLHTML($$var);
    }
}
```

Like [Thorarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198548/can-this-php-code-be-improved/1198556#1198556) I'd suggest having your `FilterALLHTML` function check for null instead though.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could already consider writing a function because you do exactly the same thing four times.

Assuming FilterALLHTML is not a custom function.

```
function Filter($var)
{
    if ($var != null)
    {
        return FilterALLHTML($var);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Or just include the null check in the FilterALLHTML function and return null from there, if needed.

So, if you can change FilterALLHTML then you'd do it like this:

```
function FilterALLHTML($var)
{
    if ($var == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        //do your filtering
       return $filteredVar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

zombat's answer is the best, but I'd add that you shouldn't really be checking for `null` either. If for some reason `FilterAllHTML` has a problem with `null` values, which it shouldn't, put the check for `null` in the `FilterAllHTML` function definition.

```
$vars = array('city', 'state', 'title', 'division');
foreach($vars as $var) {
    $$var = FilterAllHTML($$var);
}
```

Comment: actually thinking back now when I made this code almost 2 years ago I think I read that in this case it would be better performance to not call the FilterALLHTML function if it is not needed, like a NULL value would not need the function so I thought if I could filter those out before calling the function, it would be better.  I am not sure if this is better performance or not it has been so long since I did this.  I have added my function to my post if you want to see it

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Thorarin's answer, you can change your filterall function in order to accept an array as input, and passing it by reference it will modify the arrays' content.

```
$tofilter = array($city,$state,$division,$title);


filterall($tofilter);
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see it mentioned, you could always pass the parameters by reference to skip the repeated assignments:

```
function FilterALLHTML(&$var)
{
    if ($var == null)
    {
        $var = null;
    }
    else
    {
        $var = strip_tags($var);
    }
}
```

I believe you can also store references in the array but i haven't tried it.

```
foreach (array(&$city, &$state, &$title, &$division) as $var)
{
  FilterALLHTML($var);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can improve the performance, but you can shorten the syntax, but it will end up being the same to the interpreter

```
<?PHP
    $city = ($city == NULL) ? "default value" : FilterALLHTML($city);
    $state = ($state == NULL) ? "default value" : FilterALLHTML($state);
    $title = ($title == NULL) ? "default value" : FilterALLHTML($title);
    $division = ($division == NULL) ? "default value" : FilterALLHTML($division);
?>
```

"default value" should be replaced with what you would like the value to be if the variable is null

Comment: ah, down-voted :( please comment. This will give better performance than putting the "if" in the function. If the "if" is in the function it will always call the function and the "if", but putting the "if" first you will save on cpu cycles for the null values

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't consider your micro-optimization a valid argument. Also, this code is less readable than the original and functionally differs from the original.

Comment: I didn't downvote either,  but I can understand why it was down voted. IMO You just move the complexity instead of making it easier/simpler like Thorarin :)

Comment: Guess it's just me, but i prefer inline if statements of both the "if" and "else" case only have one statement, but ye, i didn't change the performance :D